# Use FabricJS and OffscreenCanvas to work with workers HTML5

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, web-worker

I am trying to investigate how to work with the `fabricJS` canvas using the `HTML5` workers and minimize the impact of code execution in the background.

I have seen in the `HTML5` `API` [OffScreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) the existence of an interface that allows to manage the canvas inside a worker.

I would like to know if I can combine this interface with `FabricJS`.

Comment: Only Chrome supports the 2d context from an OffscreenCanvas. So that would work only there. And you would probably have to tweak all the fabric's code so that every instance of an HTMLCanvasElement be replaced by an OffscreenCanvas, that all HTMLImageElements be replaced by an ImageBitmap anf that all user gesture event be removed.